# Wordpress CF7: Conditional value of field

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

Figuring out if I can change the value of a hidden input field (CF7 - Dynamic Text Extension) depending on the value of a select field. 
This is the function that gets the value of my select field called `stampfield`.

```
function dynamic_stamp_field_values ( $tag, $unused ) {

if ( $tag['name'] != 'stampfield' )
    return $tag;

$args = array (
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'stamp',
    'orderby'       => 'title',
    'order'         => 'ASC',
);

$custom_posts = get_posts($args);

if ( ! $custom_posts )
    return $tag;

foreach ( $custom_posts as $custom_post ) {

    $tag['raw_values'][] = $custom_post->post_title;
    $tag['values'][] = $custom_post->post_title;
    $tag['labels'][] = $custom_post->post_title;

}

return $tag;
}
add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_tag', 'dynamic_stamp_field_values', 10, 2);
```

the code from my form looks something like this:

```
<div class="form-group row">
<label class="col-md-3">Mærke</label>
<div class="col-md-9">
[select stampfield class:form-control include_blank]
</div></div>
```

the code might look something like this: 
**if stampfield == blank > value of hidden field is 200 else 225**
How would I do this?